# Determining length of a char* string in C++

Tags: c++, strings

I was looking to do this with `sizeof()` and I just gave up. As minimal as I can make it, I was wondering if there was a less crude way of doing the `const char *` as a convenience. I thought about doing this as a template, but I thought having another bit of generated code every time it is called seemed kinda dumb for me.

```
#include "misc.hh"
namespace mlcppl
  {
    int cpl(char * c)
    {
    char ct;
    int i = 0;

    while (ct = *(c+i))
      {
        if (ct == '\0')
          {
            break;
          }
        else
          {
            i++;
          }
      }
    return i;
  }

  int cpl(const char * c)
  {
    char * ct = (char*) c;
    return cpl(ct);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

What about:

```
std::cout << ::strlen("Plop Poop") << "\n";
```

While we are at it:

```
// use std::size_t to represent a size of something in memory
// It is non negative and is explicitly designed so it can represent
// the biggest in memory object.
//
// Pass C-String as 'char const*' (or const char* (samething))
// The compiler will automatically add a const to objects if required.
// BUT it will never remove a const (apart from 1 special case see below).
// Also the type of a string literal is 'char const*` (for the language lawyers yes it is an array but not relevant here as by the time we will see it is a pointer).
//
// Also, because you don't want to mutate the underlying string it gives
// you some slight protection from accidental assignment into the string.
std::size_t martinStringLen(char const* start)
{
    char const* end = start;

    // Look for the end of the string.
    // Your code increments two objects. I would just increment a single object
    // looking for the end of the string.
    for(;*end;++end){/*Empty*/}

    // The size is then just subtraction.
    return end - start;
}

// Unfortunately the special case is string literals: which is allowed to decay
// to char* for compatibility with old C code.
```

Other notes on your code:

```
int cpl(char * c)       // does work
int cpl(const char * c) // converts to char* so it can do work.
```

You have these two the wrong way around.
Make the `int cpl(const char * c)` version do the work. As noted above you are not mutating the object so it provides some slight protection from simple mistakes.

Also you will find the `int cpl(char * c)` version becomes unnecessary. As the compiler will automatically add const (ness) to parameters for you so you don't actually need the this version.

Other comments are same as @Konrad Rudolph

Note on the use of const.

If you put const on the right or left is a style thing. Peronally I always put it on the right. As there are a couple of corner cases (with typedef) were it does make a difference and I want to be consistent.

Note: cost always binds to the type on its `left`. unless it is the left-most part of a type declaration then it binds right. Read type right to left.

```
char const*       str1;  // const binds left to char  => (char const)*
                         // Read as: pointer to 'const char'

char const *const str2;  // const binds left => (char const) (* const)
                         // Read as: 'const pointer' to 'const char'

// From the C world (and it has leaked into C++) so a lot of people still us it
const char*       str3;  // const as left-most part binds right => (const char) *
                         // Read as: pointer to 'char const'
```

Basically str1 and str3 are identical. But the consistency of always thinking that const binds to the left makes it neater in my mind.

One place where it can make a difference is typedefs. This is because the typedef has already formed a type so any external const are applied to the typedef type as a whole thing (not as individual parts).

```
typedef char* String;
const String   str4;     // const is the left-most item so binds right.
                         // So you may expect this to be the same as str3

                         // unfortunately this is not correct as the typedef
                         // String a whole type so the const applies to `String`
                         // not to the char.

                         // Thus this is like const (char*)
                         // Which is the same as (char*) const
                         // Read: const 'pointer to char' so once set the pointer
                         // can not be moved.
 // If on the other hand you never put const in the left-most position then
 // this problem never even comes up.
```

So two reasons not to put const as the left-most part of the type.

Comment: I now i could use strlen, god knows wjat else goes into that function, and i wanted to try my hand at it myself

Comment: @alexhairyman Wait, what are you up to? Are you doing an academic assignment writing `strlen` from scratch? If yes, look into Keith's answer and understand the principles behind it, because your original posted code looks very un-C (and un-C++, for that matter). If, on the other hand, you're doing production work, then you **should** use stock `strlen` unless you have a very, very solid argument against doing that. Otherwise, it's a dangerous case of Not Invented Here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here).

Comment: I dunno, I have just a little project I am using to learn c++ features @ [mlcppl](https://github.com/alexhairyman/mlcppl) Don't make fun of me bros!

Comment: Okay, I get the first example using the for, but I don't think it is as staightforward as counting, although it is another way. Upvote for you too!

Answer (score 5):

`std::strlen` will give you the length a zero-terminated string, like Loki said. If you want to know how it’s implemented, just look up its implementation.

And Keith has given a short, albeit slightly cryptic, implementation.

But since this is *Code Review*, let’s go over your code, shall we. We’ll start at the end.

```
int cpl(const char * c)
{
    char * ct = (char*) c;
    return cpl(ct);
}
```

Two things to note:

1. Don’t use C-style casts, they hide bugs and are generally strongly discouraged; use C++ casts instead – `const_cast` in this case.
2. Don’t use `const_cast` unless you really have to, it’s also quite dangerous. In particular, it can easily lead to undefined behaviour. And it’s unnecessary in your case: your code will never actually modify the string so why un-`const` it?

In fact, your non-`const` variant of the function is unnecessary since there’s an implicit conversion from `char*` to `char const*`.

Next, what does “`cpl`” actually stand for? I have no idea. Use a meaningful name and avoid abbreviations in general.

Now to the main function. I’ll note right at the start that `c` is a bad name for the argument. Single-letter names are sometimes OK but `c` suggests that the type of the variable is actually `char`. If you insist on a single-letter identifier, use `s` for “string”.

The return type and the loop variable in your code are `int` but they will never be negative. C++ provides a type for this – `unsigned int` – which is more suitable here.

Next,

```
while (ct = *(c+i))
```

This is cryptic. First off, why do you write `*(c+1)` instead of `c[i]`? Secondly, while C++ allows assignments inside expressions, and some developers encourage this, it should still be used sparingly. You don’t really need the variable `ct` here anyway. It certainly doesn’t help readability (especially not with the once again cryptic name).

Thirdly, C++ is once again forgiving and lets you test a character value for “truthiness”. But just because C++ understands this doesn’t make it understandable. I’d argue that testing a char for truthiness is a nonsensical operation. Use an explicit comparison instead, this is more readable.

The body of the loop contains nothing as much as redundancy. (I’ll note in passing that even with the `if` in it, this could be *two lines* instead of *eight*, and would be more readable).

The `if` is totally redundant. You are testing **the same** condition as in the loop head, and the condition inside the loop will *never* be true. You probably missed that because, as I noted above, the loop head is cryptic.

Finally, it’s convention in C++ to use prefix-`++` instead of postfix unless necessary. The reason for this is that the prefix operation is *sometimes faster, and never  slower*, than the postfix operation. Now, this is irrelevant in your case since you are incrementing an integer but it may play a role for user-defined types.

Your whole code can be condensed to this simple, readable code:

```
unsigned int length(char const* s) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0')
        ++i;

    return i;
}
```

Some people would instead write it as follows; the result is more or less indistinguishable:

```
unsigned int length(char const* s) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (*s++ != '\0')
        ++i;

    return i;
}
```

(And note that here, we *do* need postfix increment.)

Finally, here’s a recursive implementation, just to get a one-liner:

```
unsigned int length(char const* s) {
    return *s == '\0' ? 0 : 1 + length(s + 1);
}
```

Note that although this is recursive, and not even tail recursive, modern compilers will very likely recognise this and produce efficient code that doesn’t overflow the stack for long strings (tested on GCC 4.7 with `-O2`, works; but doesn’t without optimisations – not surprisingly).

Comment: I thought, why not *(c+i)? I can see how that behavior works, it simply gives the value pointed to c with an offset of +i. I don't know much about memory allocation in c++\

Comment: maybe another comment to the terseness of `while (ct = *(c+i))` would be to focus on making the code readable and let the compiler worry about the optimization.